# JSON.parse error in ruby.

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I need to JSON.parse a variable called :

```
attr = "{
           "title": "AAAAAAA",
           "description": "BBBBBBB",
           "body": "AAAA"BBBBB"ccccccc",
           "img_url": "http: aaaaa.jpg" }"
```

And I end up getting an error (JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token).

I think it might come from the multiple quotes at "body" key value, but i can't figure a way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to parse an invalid json string with `JSON.parse`.

Where does that string come from? If it is under your control you should make it valid.

You can fix it by surrounding the string with single quotes `'` instead of double quotes and by escaping the `"` with `\"`:

```
> attr = '{
       "title": "AAAAAAA",
       "description": "BBBBBBB",
       "body": "AAAA\"BBBBB\"ccccccc",
       "img_url": "http: aaaaa.jpg" }'
> JSON.parse(attr)
# => { "title" => "AAAAAAA", "description" => "BBBBBBB", "body" => "AAAA\"BBBBB\"ccccccc", "img_url" => "http: aaaaa.jpg" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `%Q` for a multiline string:

```
attr = %Q[{
       "title": "AAAAAAA",
       "description": "BBBBBBB",
       "body": "AAAA\\"BBBBB\\"ccccccc",
       "img_url": "http: aaaaa.jpg" }]
```

Comment: No results.
JSON.parse(attr)
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
attr = %Q[{
       "title": "AAAAAAA",
       "description": "BBBBBBB",
       "body": "AAAA\\"BBBBB\\"ccccccc",
       "img_url": "http: aaaaa.jpg" }]
```

Console test output:

```
[190] pry(main)> attr = %Q[{
[190] pry(main)*        "title": "AAAAAAA",
[190] pry(main)*        "description": "BBBBBBB",
[190] pry(main)*        "body": "AAAA\\"BBBBB\\"ccccccc",
[190] pry(main)*        "img_url": "http: aaaaa.jpg" }]
=> "{\n       \"title\": \"AAAAAAA\",\n       \"description\": \"BBBBBBB\",\n       \"body\": \"AAAA\\\"BBBBB\\\"ccccccc\",\n       \"img_url\": \"http: aaaaa.jpg\" }"
[191] pry(main)> JSON.parse attr
=> {"title"=>"AAAAAAA",
 "description"=>"BBBBBBB",
 "body"=>"AAAA\"BBBBB\"ccccccc",
 "img_url"=>"http: aaaaa.jpg"}
[197] pry(main)> puts _["body"]
AAAA"BBBBB"ccccccc
=> nil
```